# How to make Eclipse use older Android API 15

Tags: android, eclipse

I am learning how to develop Android apps, using Eclipse. New to all of this, and apparently there is a bug that messes up the "Graphical Layout" pane of Android XML files when you add a box of plain-text. I've read solutions saying to change the input type, but I'm not deep enough into Android for it to really make a difference between using API 16 or 15. I am currently using 16, I downloaded 15 today, and am trying to find a way to make Eclipse use the older API. How do I switch Eclipse over to use API 15 instead of 16? (I'd prefer not to uninstall API 16, but if I must, oh well).

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944074/eclipse-android-change-api-level

Comment: oh. i saw this earlier but i didn't realize that API 16/15 both correspond to an actual number like 1.5 or 2.1. Should have known, sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the manifest file and change the line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="number-of-version-you-want" />
```