# Android 5 material design problems

Tags: android, material-design

I'm new to android programming and I just found out what material design is.

I have a few problems

1. How can I make an icon like google+'s or google app's?
   (thay have shades and a little different from others)
2. How can i add material design to my app?
   (status bar and things like this...)
3. How can I make a FAB??
   And about the color of status bar, I've seen some apps title bar are lighter and the status bar is darker
   I don't want my app to be like that
   What can I do about these?
4. How can I make my app run on lower APIs?
   Oh im using eclipse
   Please dont give me links to google developers because our country is forbidden

Comment: Instead of asking here, you should try searching for guides on the World Wide Web. You will surely find all the question you made and also with wide explanations

Comment: Use a VPN, connect to the Google Developers website and start reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding #1,

```
Right click on 'app' or the beginning of your project tree > New > Image Asset
```

You should be able to customize most, if not all, aspects of your icon in there.

Regarding #2,

```
I don't understand exactly what you're asking. You can customize your Action Bar and stuff like that if you choose.
```

Regarding #3,

Go to  res ->  drawable right-click and create a new drawable resource and name it circle.xml. Now in the newly created file add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:top="8px">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="3px"
                    android:left="3px"
                    android:right="3px"
                    android:top="3px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="2px"
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                    android:top="2px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="2px"
                    android:left="2px"
                    android:right="2px"
                    android:top="2px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
</item>

<item >

    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#FFBB00" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">

                <solid android:color="@color/ColorPrimary" />


            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>

</item>
```

You must notice that the circular shape is enclosed in a ripple tag this tag ensures the circle reacts to on touch with the ripple effect on lollipop devices.
Now go to res -> layout right-click and select create a new layout resource, name it tool_bar.xml and the add the following code to that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Now go to res -> values create a new resource file name it colors.xml and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="ColorPrimary">#FF5722</color>
<color name="ColorPrimaryDark">#E64A19</color> // you can change the colors if you want, this is orange
</resources>
```

Now go to activity_main.xml and add the following code to it. Also make sure you add the icon which you want to show inside your FAB to your project.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"

    ></include>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextAct1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Edit this to say anything"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />


</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Source for number 3: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/03/how-to-make-floating-action-button-fab.html

Regarding #4,

Using Eclipse, it may not change the SDK version correctly just going right click and properties. Open the manifest file and change the line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="number-of-version-you-want" />
```

Source for number 4: [Eclipse Android Change API Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944074/eclipse-android-change-api-level)

Goodluck man, check out the links if you can.

Comment: Thank yoy for all of that but at the last part you said how can i change the api level i knew that but i say how can i use material design on lower api

Comment: Which API are you targeting as your minimum in this case?

Comment: I don't know! But I've seen some apps working in api 8 and they have material design

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to look at the developer website, you can instead look through the code samples. You can download the samples using the SDK manager.

For example in the samples folder /ui/views in the Lollipop SDKs you can find samples for `FloatingActionButton`, `CardView`, `Elevation`, `RevealEffect` and many others.